# Encode URL with dot

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, url-routing, urlencode

I need to encode a url that contains a dot character ".". It's a ASP.NET MVC routing, but the url contains a ".". Is there a way?

For example, I'm trying to get this url: "/Products/Beverages/Drink.Best/Teste"

There's a "." in that... And I need to encode that... is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example, dots usually is not problems in URL´s at least not where I have seen them

Comment: Also, you could show us what you've tried and what the result is.

Comment: @Andre: why do you think you need to encode that dot?

Comment: Because browser is not accepeting this url with ".", ok?

Comment: But every normal webpage has a dot in it usualy followed by asp, aspx, php, jsp or something, I cannot se any reason this would be different? Do you have an example URL that does not work that we could test?

Comment: Are you getting an error from your browser about the dot, or is the error coming from the logic on the page?

Comment: Try these
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13082446/95970
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12151501/95970

Answer (score 1):

You can test your encoding output with the URLEncoder at FooBabel - [URLCodec](http://www.foobabel.com/apps/cs/URLCodec)

Answer (score 0):

"." message is it from Routing engine?

check out link [Url Manipulation](http://dheemhi.blogspot.com/2010/12/url-manipulation-implementing-routebase.html)