# ASP.NET MVC Url Route supporting (dot)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, url-routing, global-asax

I hope that you can help me with the below problem.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 on IIS7 and would like my application to support username's with dots.

Example: http://localhost/john.lee

This is how my Global.asax looks like: (http://localhost/{username})

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UserList",
    "{username}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "ListAll" }
);
```

The applications works when I access other pages such as http://localhost/john.lee/details etc.

But the main user page doesn't work, I would like the app to work like Facebook where http://www.facebook.com/john.lee is supported.

I used below code and it didn't work for me at all:

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

I was able to use below code and get the app to accept dots but I definitely wouldn't like to use below code for many different reason, please tell me there is a way to overcome this problem.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163401/dot-symbol-in-url

Comment: I have the same issue, but in IIS 6.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. It works for me in IIS Express (so it should also work in IIS 7.0+). Also you seem to be indicating an url of the form `/john.lee/details` but according to your route definition you cannot specify an action. It will always use the `ListAll` action. So the problem is not really related to the dot here. It's probably more about your routes.

Comment: No Darin, you misunderstood me, http://localhost/john.lee is using the above route (ListAll), but /john.lee/details is using a different route of course, but somehow that works. I think this has something to do with IIS, by enabling a dot on usernames, it would allow something like localhost/default.aspx (default.aspx being a username and not a file on the root folder). I really need to find a way around this.

Comment: Basically by enabling dots on the username, someone's username could be default.aspx while another person's username could be john.lee but IIS will get confused by that i pressume?

Comment: try posting up your entire routing table, my immediate guess is another route is conflicting and causing issues.

Comment: I have actually commented out ALL other routes in Global.asax, the above one is the ONLY one left.

If I type localhost/john.lee it does not work.
If I type localhost/john.lee/ it works and the page comes up.

How can I make it so it adds a slash in the background though the slash isn't present on the address bar and not add a slash when its there on the address bar? maybe this would be a shortcut?

Comment: just to be sure, did you mean that `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />` does or does not work? Making a sample mvc3 application with one route very similar to your own works as long as `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` is true. IIRC, the issue you seem to be having would be caused by IIS trying to map your url to a file of type `lee` named `john` rather than your route.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. So the best solution for me is:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
<system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 63):

Add a UrlRoutingHandler to the web.config. This requires your url to be a bit more specific however (f.e. /Users/john.lee).
This forces every url starting with /Users to be treated as a MVC url:

```
<system.webServer>    
  <handlers>      
    <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" 
         type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler, 
               System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
         path="/Users/*" 
         verb="GET"/>      
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I needed this for my api controller and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use this to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331516/asp-net-mvc-routing-add-html-extension-to-routes

Comment: I really don't get how this works; `Cannot create an abstract class.` http://pastebin.com/vuQ2WnWZ

Comment: At first I didn't think this worked, then I realized I was putting it in ~/Views/web.config instead of ~/web.config. Ashame you have to put the full absolute path especially when the app's deployment virtual directory might change.

Comment: What does `System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler` do? Cannot find an explanation why this works

Comment: Very old ansser that solves my current problem.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

Just add this section to Web.config, and all requests to the route/{*pathInfo} will be handled by the specified handler, even when there are dots in pathInfo. (taken from ServiceStack MVC Host Web.config example and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12151501/801189)

This should work for both IIS 6 & 7. You could assign specific handlers to different paths after the 'route' by modifying path="*" in 'add' elements

```
  <location path="route">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" />
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
    <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
        <add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Comment: This seems to work as well as using System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler - I'm just not sure which is better or more efficient - UrlRoutingHandler seems to be specifically geared towards routing.

Comment: So, could anyone explain what is the actual difference between TransferRequestHandler and UrlRoutingHandler? Which of them should be preferred?

Comment: Does anyone still uses IIS7 stack in 2017!? .NET Core and Kestrel are so much better!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone getting an 'Cannot create abstract class' exception when using the `UrlRoutingHandler` approach, it's likely due to:

- Using a restricted 'path' (e.g. `path="/Files/*"`) in your web.config declaration, and
- A folder/path with the same name exists in your project

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the dot is the problem here. AFAIK the only char that should not be in the user name is a /

Without seeing the route that matches `john.lee/details` it's hard to say what's wrong, but I'm guessing that you have another route that matches the url, preventing the user details route from being matched correctly.

I recommend using a tool like [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) to figure out what route is being matched.