# MVC 3.0 cannot route a url with double dots at the end

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

Assume there is a link as follows:

domain.com/Link/Details/60/AbiWord-2.6.5-is-a-free-software-word-processor--Wind%2cMac%2cLinux%2c..

Since there are two dots and the end, mvc is confused by the extension i think so .
Therefore, I just face with "Server Error in '/' Application.".

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");



        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

                    routes.MapRoute(
            "ViewLink", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Link", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

When i remove tow last dots at end then my page will be loaded. so how can handle this issue ? I dont want to remove those dots

Comment: Isn't SO written in MVC3?  It works fine on this site.  I think it's your server configuration.  What server are you running this on?

Comment: yes it is in mvc 3, what do mean what server? surely it is windows server.

Comment: whats your specific exception details?

Comment: When i remove tow last dots at end then my page will be loaded. so how can handle this issue ? I dont want to remove those dots

Comment: IIS 6 ,IIS 7 , IIS 7.5? Are you getting a HTTP 404, a HTTP 500, what?

Comment: Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Url Route supporting (dot)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273987/asp-net-mvc-url-route-supporting-dot)

Comment: @MystereMan if you look at the url you will be able to see there are more dots inside that. it has only problem with two last dots.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem here is that the request doesn't even make it to ASP.NET MVC. The webserver sees it as a problem before it gets there. :(

Apart from escaping the dots, or removing the trailing one, not sure what you can do.