# ASP.NET MVC routes with "." not working in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I have simple route map like:

```
routes.MapRoute("Test", "test/{action}/{id}", new {controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = ""});
```

My route paths are like:

```
"/test/do-something/1.0.1"
```

Which works completely fine in local testing and self hosted .NET 4.5 on IIS7+

However, when I host it in Azure, it seems to have issues with the ID containing two ".", telling me that "*The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.*".
When I change the path to `"/test/do-something/1"` it works on Azure as well.

Why does Azure seem to prohibit ID's with "." and what can I do about it?

Comment: It seems to be a problem more with MVC framework rather than Azure itself. There is a similar problem described here http://stackoverflow.com/q/9273987/1916110

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using '-' in your id as opposed to '.' (periods), it's more friendly in terms of SEO.

If you really want to get it working with periods, you could use a tool called **URLScan**.

[What is URLScan?](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/working-with-urlscan/urlscan-faq)

There is an option to configure:

> **AllowDotInPath=0**
>
> By default, this option is set to 0. If this option is set to 0,
>   URLScan rejects any request that contains multiple periods (.). This
>   prevents attempts to disguise requests for dangerous file name
>   extensions by putting a safe file name extension in the path
>   information or query string portion of the URL. For example, if this
>   option...

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326444/en-us) is a link to the configuration.

Comment: This is working fine on local machine as well as a self hosted IIS server - the only issue is on Azure

Comment: How is your site set up on Azure? on a VM or Website?