# Url routing like facebook asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I am new to asp.net and currently learning url routing

In facebook link(https://www.facebook.com/james.wood) how does `james.wood` work?

I tried doing the same thing in my asp.net by using this code added in my global

```
route.MapPageRoute("Profile", "epubtest/profile/{profileid}", "~/epubtest/Profile.aspx");
```

But I cant make it work with **dot** like `james.wood`

Does the dot means another parameter or just one single parameter?

It works without a dot on it just one single word

Comment: What happens when you try with a dot?

Comment: @haim770 it will register as a new page. and I got `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found`

Comment: It probably saw `.wood` as an extension

Comment: [This will be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273987/asp-net-mvc-url-route-supporting-dot)

Answer (score 0):

1) You can add this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "User",
    url: "{username}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Destiny", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { username = new UserNameConstraint() }
);
```

2) Create this class:

```
public class UserNameConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        List<string> users = new List<string>() { "username1", "username2" };

        var username = values["username"].ToString().ToLower();

        return users.Any(x => x.ToLower() == username);
    }
}
```

3) DestinyController

```
public class DestinyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string username)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I hope I've helped.
Hugs!